# How to implement a beam search decoder in an SageMaker hosting endpoint?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, beam-search

I've created a SageMaker model for a Seq2Seq neural network, and then started a SageMaker endpoint:

```
create_endpoint_config_response = sage.create_endpoint_config(
    EndpointConfigName = endpoint_config_name,
    ProductionVariants=[{
        'InstanceType':'ml.m4.xlarge', 
        'InitialInstanceCount':1,
        'ModelName':model_name,
        'VariantName':'AllTraffic'}])

create_endpoint_response = sage.create_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name,
    EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name)
```

This standard endpoint does not support beam search. What is the best approach for creating a SageMaker endpoint that supports beam search?

Comment: Can you explain how and why you want to use Beam Search in an endpoint? I'm not familiar with the concept. Also do you use pre build algorithms, pass your own estimator or do you build your own docker file?

Comment: The particular model I've trained has multiple possibly correct output sequences (think of it as a one to many seq2seq problem), and the standard decoder will only output a single prediction for a single input sequence. Using Beam Search at inference time it's possible to output multiple candidate output sequences ranked by probability.

The neural net uses Sockeye not a custom algorithm, following Amazon's tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/create-a-word-pronunciation-sequence-to-sequence-model-using-amazon-sagemaker/) and running inside a notebook instance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I believe the only solution is to create your own docker container for inference. This way you can load your already trained model and do with it whatever you like. [This example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own) is a good place to start when you want to learn about how to use docker in sagemaker.

For your use case it would be best to find the source code for the sagemaker builtin 
seq2seq model (the builtin algorithms are also just docker images), modify it to your needs, built the modified docker container and load it to your aws ecr, from where you can load it with sagemaker.

Unfortunately I don't know if the source code for the docker containers is publicly available (didn't find it on the first try).